# Копирование Map Java

Tags: java

У меня есть два интерфейса

```
public interface Walked {
void walk();
}


public interface Runned extends Walked {
    void run();
}
```

Так же есть класс

```
public class SimpleObject implements Runned {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm run");
    }

    @Override
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("I'm walk");
    }
}
```

И есть класс

```
public class SimpleObjectSaver {
    private final Map<Integer, Runned> map= new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Integer, Walked> getMap() {
        //????
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как мне реализовать метод getMap() у класса SimpleObjectSaver, чтобы он вернул map, но преобразовав его к Map. Я знаю что коллекции инвариантны, поэтому полиморфизм тут не сработает, есть ли какой то способ преобразования коллекции Map к Map, не такой как например (или с использованием итератора).

```
public Map<Integer, Walked> getMap() {
    Map<Integer, Walked> returnedMap=new HashMap<>();

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Runned> entry: map.entrySet()) {
       Integer key = entry.getKey();
       Walked value = entry.getValue();
        returnedMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return returnedMap;
}
```

Comment: Можно просто в конструктор засунуть. [Четвертый в списке конструкторов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: ```public Map<Integer, **? extends Walked**> getMap() {``` ?